# NodeJS, adding actions to a Promise in a While loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

so I am fairly new to using Promises in NodeJS. I am trying to dynamically create a promise with a few actions depending on the characters in a string.

```
//let actions = [];
getPromise = get(srcBucket, srcKey); // Get the image

//Apply transformations to image.
while (transformations.length > 0) {
  let op = transformations.charAt(0);
  if (op == 'B') {
    getPromise.then(image => blur(image));
  } else if (op == 'R') {
    getPromise.then(image => resize(image));
  } else if (op == 'O') {
    getPromise.then(image => rotate(image));
  } else if (op == 'S') {
    getPromise.then(image => sepia(image));
  } else if (op == 'C') {
    getPromise.then(image => compress(image));
  }
  transformations = transformations.substring(1);
}

getPromise.then(modified => put(destBucket, destKey, modified))
  .then(() => putSAAFOutput(inspector))
  .then(() => {
  console.log('Success');
  return resolve('Success');
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  return reject(error);
});
```

The get method in the first line gets an image from Amazon S3. Then I want to make a number of transformations to that image based of the characters in the "transformations" string. Each of the transformation functions (blur, resize, sepia, etc) all return their own promises.

When I run this function none of the transformations are being applied to the image! Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `getpromise = getPromise.then(image => blur(image))` perhaps?

Comment: Fixed! Awesome thank you so much! I did not know that .then returned a promise but it makes sense now. Add this as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already see the fix is `getPromise = getPromise.then(...)`.  I thought I'd just add that this type of code looks a bit cleaner if you DRY it up with a lookup table instead of a big `if/else` and iterating through a list of characters accumulating a promise chain sounds like a job for `.reduce()`.

```
let getPromise = get(srcBucket, srcKey); // Get the image

const transformMap = {
    B: blur,
    R: resize,
    O: rotate,
    S: sepia,
    C: compress
};

//Apply transformations to image.
getPromise = transformations.split("").reduce((p, op) => {
    let fn = transformMap[op];
    if (fn) {
        return p.then(image => fn(image));
    } else {
        return p;
    }
}, getPromise);

return getPromise.then(modified => put(destBucket, destKey, modified))
  .then(() => putSAAFOutput(inspector))
  .then(() => {
  console.log('Success');
  return 'Success';
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  throw error;
});
```

In addition, the fact that you're using `somePromise.then(resolve).catch(reject)` at the end of your promise chain apparently means that you've wrapped all this inside your own `new Promise()`.  Doing that is a promise anti-pattern and is not necessary.  Instead, you can just return the promise you already have.   Instead of `resolve('Success');`, you can just do `return 'Success'`.  And, instead of `reject(error);`, you can just do `throw error`.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing would require you to *chain* the promises returned at every *step*

so `getPromise = getPromise.then( ... do something else and return a promise ...)`

is the pattern you want

like so

```
getPromise = get(srcBucket, srcKey); // Get the image

//Apply transformations to image.
while (transformations.length > 0) {
  let op = transformations.charAt(0);
  if (op == 'B') {
    getPromise = getPromise.then(image => blur(image));
  } else if (op == 'R') {
    getPromise = getPromise.then(image => resize(image));
  } else if (op == 'O') {
    getPromise = getPromise.then(image => rotate(image));
  } else if (op == 'S') {
    getPromise = getPromise.then(image => sepia(image));
  } else if (op == 'C') {
    getPromise = getPromise.then(image => compress(image));
  }
  transformations = transformations.substring(1);
}

getPromise.then(modified => put(destBucket, destKey, modified))
  .then(() => putSAAFOutput(inspector))
  .then(() => {
  console.log('Success');
  return resolve('Success');
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  return reject(error);
});
```